# Colon in grpc url while using wire

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, proto, google-photos-api, square-wire

I'm trying to make a call to grpc syntax URL:  `https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:search`
by using [Wire](https://github.com/square/wire) framework.

First problem is putting `/v1` in path as below configuration ignores it:

```
GrpcClient.Builder()
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .baseUrl("https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1")
            .build()
```

Such config make calls to `https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com`

Second problem is colon in the URL. Here is my proto config:

```
service MediaItems {
  rpc Search(SearchMediaItemCommand) returns (stream SearchMediaItemUpdate) {}
}
```

With this I end up with call to URL: `https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/MediaItems/Search`

1. How to add v1 to the base URL? (I can do this by adding interceptor in okhttpclient but it doesn't feel right)
2. How to config protocol for colon (:) in URL?

Comment: Are you confident that Google provides gRPC bindings for Photos API? The `photoslibrary.googleapis.com` endpoint definitely supports REST. The method  [`mediaItems:search`](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/mediaItems/search) is documented. There's a definitive list of gRPC [bindings](https://github.com/googleapis/go-genproto/tree/main/googleapis) for Golang and Photos isn't part of the set.

Comment: If that endpoint **does** provide a gRPC endpoint then you will probably need to drop `https://` from the URL and add `:443`.